# does this strategy that use core data with multiple thread will block main thread ?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have read many blogs that recommend use core data in multiple thread with the following pattern. 
[image]

but the question is if there are a lot of records I have to load when app starts, I have to use the NSFetchdResultsController to fetch all records in CoreData. Because it will run in main thread(main moc), does it will block the main thread? If I want to fetch some records, can I use Temporary Background MOC to fetch? and how to do it?

Comment: If something is running on main thread then yes, it will block the UI,  but you can fetch results from core data on a bg thread.

Comment: how to fetch results in a background thread and notify the main moc?

Comment: With GCD there are lots of tutorials about this, but you have to be very careful with the ManagedObjectContext when you are using threads and CoreData. Basically every thread has it's own managed object context, and you can fetch/process data on a background thread and after that you post the results on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You usually configure batching on a fetch request for NSFetchedResultsController. Then when you perform fetch in NSFetchedResultsController, and it in turn executes the fetch request, that request is very minimal, because it basically fetches only object IDs and no data. Later, when some object from the results is accessed (typically in -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:), first batch is being fetched. This fetch also takes little time (if you configure small enough batch size). When you scroll and access the first object that is not in a batch, the next batch is fetched and so on. This way no big fetches are performed on the main thread.

There is one problem with this approach and the pattern you've chosen. For some reason batching doesn't work when fetch request is executed in a child context. It works only in contexts connected to the persistent store coordinator directly.